# ¿Como hago para que "* " se imprima tantas veces quiera sin usar un for? Algo así como usar un string(n, '*')

Tags: c++, string

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es básicamente el problema, quiero repetir varias veces una string sin usar mucho espacio, por eso digo sin usar un for.

Comment: Y puedes ocupar funciones recursivas?

Comment: sí, pero me gustaría que el problema se solucione en la menor cantidad de lineas con la menor cantidad de espacio. Almenos así es como dicen que será mejor.

Comment: Cuando debes repetir algo X veces no hay nada más eficiente que un for. Tampoco hay nada de malo en escribir varias líneas, lo importante es que el código sea ordenado y legible. Incluso la mayor legibilidad se realiza creando muchas funciones, donde cada una realiza un proceso pequeño, y al hacer esto tienes un programa con muchas más líneas de código

Comment: Ahh perfecto, gracias! usaré un for en ese caso, gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si es por hacerlo más sencillo, puedes usar un while para la lógica de tu método.

```
while(n-- > 0) {
cout << "*"
}
```